# How to modify/add addition variable to service json after successfully register.json?

Tags: 7, users, services

I am able to get the response after register using service register.json

Response:

```
    {
        "uid": "10",
        "uri": "http://example.com/apps_api/user/10"
    }
```

Input:

> { "name":"smart", "pass":"smart", "mail":"tushar@smalution.com",
>   "status":"1", "roles":[ "3" ] }

I get all the information `"uri": "http://example.com/apps_api/user/10"` .
I just want to get the "name", "mail", "role" in response.

Do not need to go again `"uri": "http://example.com/apps_api/user/10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to get back the raw text password without hacking on the logintoboggan / user modules themselves (similar to what is shown in my question).

However, I solved my same purpose of providing immediate-login-upon-registration for Services/API calls using the services_token_access module. This code only hooks onto a success registration then ads the services_token to the response which is now the only thing my client now needs for validation.

```
function HOOK_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {

if ( gettype($result) == 'array' && isset($result['uri']) && isset($result['uid'])) { // THIS CONDITION MATCHES THE DEFAULT RESPONSE OF A SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION. 
        $user = (object)$result;
        $user = user_load($user->uid);
        $user = HOOK_services_account_object_alter($user);
        $result = array('token'=>$user->services_token, 'user'=>$user);
    }
}


function HOOK_services_account_object_alter(&$user) {
    $user->services_token = services_token_access_update_token($user->uid, FALSE); // essential for logging in later
    $user->specialstuff = 'whatever else you need';
}
```

(The services_token_access module is not particularly popular and barely supported, but worked for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Add custom code/module to modify the service response, check [hook_services_endpoint_response_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_endpoint_response_alter/7) and all other similar alter hooks [services alter hooks](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!docs!services.alter.api.php/7)

e.g.:

```
function MODULENAME_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  if ($controller->callback == '_user_resource_create') {
    if ($result->uid) {
      $user = user_load($result->uid);
      $result->user = $user;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please explain little bit more.

Comment: give me a min, sharing a working example, also it will be hook_services_request_postprocess_alter

Comment: check e.g. code

Comment: Add the code but still getting same response. No change in Response.

Comment: change MODULENAME and clear cache, also which API are you using exactly? check the condition for $controller->callback

Comment: Changed the module name, cleared the cache checked all possible way. Actually $controller->callback gives null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34245/discussion-between-smalution-and-nikunj).

Comment: hi @Smalution, let me know if you are still not able to get this working

Comment: Thanks @nikunj for your helping nature. Currently i am busy with some other task to meet the deadline. Still i am having the same issue but i will work on it later. Thanks again..

Comment: @Smalution : still busy with that other task?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens not at all. I was getting the same issue. I have post my answer which solve my issue. I will accept it. Thanks